# Degradar color de fondo en el encabezado de un JTable

Tags: java-swing, jtable

Tengo un **JTable** el cual **reenderizo** el **encabezado** con un **DefaultTableCellRenderer** para cambiar color de título, alineación y agregar borde.

Para degradar el color de fondo del encabezado le sobreescribo el paintComponent a mi clase **DefaultTableCellRenderer**, **pero me anula el texto**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class EncabezadoDegradado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new VentanaConTabla();
    }  
}
class VentanaConTabla extends JFrame{

    public VentanaConTabla() {
        setTitle("Degradando color fondo encabezado");
        setBounds(400, 100, 400, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Lamina lamina =new Lamina();
        add(lamina);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class Lamina extends JPanel{

        public Lamina() {
            setLayout(null);
            DefaultTableModel dtmTabla =new DefaultTableModel();
            JTable tabla =new JTable(dtmTabla);
            dtmTabla.addColumn("Mi título de encabezado");            
            RendererEncabezado rendEncabez =new RendererEncabezado();
            tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderRenderer(rendEncabez);
            JScrollPane scrollTabla = new JScrollPane(tabla);
            scrollTabla.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 400);
            add(scrollTabla);
        }
    }
    class RendererEncabezado extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

        private final Color COLOR_1 = Color.GRAY;
        private final Color COLOR_2 = Color.BLACK;
        private final GradientPaint gradientPaint =new GradientPaint(0, 0, COLOR_1, 200, 0, COLOR_2);

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
            Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            comp.setForeground(Color.BLUE);//queda anulado por el paintComponent

            setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

            return comp;
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
           g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Será porque primero invocas el pintado original con `super` y después lo sobre-dibujas con un rectángulón?

Comment: @Sal supuestamente siempre hay que llamar al super, igualmente probé sin el super y tampoco funciona

Comment: Digo que pruebes llamar el super después de dibujar el rectángulo.

Comment: @Sal ahi lo probé y, como era de esperar, ahora no me pinta el fondo, o sea queda anulado todo lo que está antes del `super.paintComponent(g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llama el método de la superclase después de dibujar el rectángulo.

```
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
           g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

           super.paintComponent(g);
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de Windows, debido a sutilezas en la implementación pudiera ser que necesites invocar al delegado de UI en lugar de `paintComponent()`.

```
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
           g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

           //super.paintComponent(g);
           this.ui.paint(g,this);
        }
```

Comment: Por qué a mi no me funciona? No has cambiado nada del código más que la llamada a super al final?

Comment: Estoy usando Windows 7, NetBeans 8.2. Ejecutando en cmd: `java -version` me dice: 1.8.0_211, pero en NetBeans pestaña help/abaut me dice: 1.8.0_151

Comment: Ahora cambié mi versión de JDK por esta otra: 1.8.0_241. Pero todo sigue igual. Seguro que no has modificado alguna otra parte del código?

Comment: Aparte de eso sólo hice las clases anidadas para tener un solo .java. OS X 10.10 NetBeans 8.2  y Java 1.8.0_45.

Comment: Ahora si !! El toque mágico fue eso de la sutileza de Windows. Ni idea que es eso del delegado de UI..